# MySQL import from csv file with character exceptions

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to import a CSV files into my MySQL table using the following query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\machines.csv'
INTO TABLE `machines` 
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 0 LINES;
```

However it give the following error

> 1406- Data too long for column 'technicalInfo' at row 10334

It seems that the issue is that the row contains a [⌀](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter) character in the technicalInfo column.

Is it possible to remove/replace this character within the query?

(N.B. Obviously another solution would be to remove it from the csv file itself. The problem is that I am likely to be importing different versions of this file multiple times every day, so I'd rather build it in to the query.)

Comment: did you try `mysqlimport` utility?

Comment: does changing your [`character set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)` to utf-8` help?

Comment: @abhinav Thanks. Looks like it's supposed to be "utf8" (without the dash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the '⌀' character is not available in the `latin1` character set and that is why you're getting the error. Can you change the character set to `utf8` and see if you still experience the problem?

[1] MYSQL Error 1406 details: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18908

Comment: Hmm...now I'm getting the following error: `1366- Incorrect string value:  '\xEF\xBB\xBF0-0...' for columm 'technicalInfo' at row 1`

Comment: Also check that the **machines** table's character set is `utf8` and not `latin1`.

Comment: The machines table is now set to utf8, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can change or remove that symbol, e.g. -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\machines.csv'
INTO TABLE `machines` 
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 0 LINES
(column1, column2, @var1) -- specify column names here
SET column3 = REPLACE(@var1, '⌀', ''); -- replace it with '!'
```

Comment: This give me the following error: `1270- Illegal mix of collations (latin_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT),(utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE),(utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'`